# Division of multiple dimension data in pandas using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, division

Since pandas can't work in multi-dimensions, I usually stack the data row-wise and use a dummy column to mark the data dimensions.  Now, I need to divide one dimension by another.

For example, given this dataframe where key define the dimensions

```
index  key  value
0       a   10
1       b   12
2       a   20
3       b   15
4       a   8
5       b   9
```

I want to achieve this:

```
index   key value   ratio_a_b    
0      a    10     0.833333    
1      b    12     NaN
2      a    20     1.33333
3      b    15     NaN
4      a    8      0.888889
5      b    9      NaN
```

Is there a way to do it using groupby?

Comment: Just curious what you've tried already and what errors you may have encountered

Comment: are `a` and `b` always come in pair like in your sample?

Comment: @Shane 
In a simple case.. groupby('key') , retrive the grouped dataframe using groupby.get_group. make index of group('a") same as group('b') then divide

Comment: @QuangHoang 
Not really..

Comment: So every `a` is divided by the next `b` value?

Comment: @QuangHoang
I use the key column as a dimension annotation bc pandas cannot handle multi dimension data. usually I do a query on the dimension. Now the dataframe is getting to complex, so I thought groupby could be the solution

Comment: so you have, say `n` dimension data, and you want to divide dimension `0,1,2,...` by dimension `n`?

Comment: @QuangHoang
Correct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need (and should not use) `groupby` for this:

```
# interpolate the b values
s = df['value'].where(df['key'].eq('b')).bfill()

# mask the a values and divide
# change to df['key'].ne('b') if you have many values of a
df['ratio'] = df['value'].where(df['key'].eq('a')).div(s)
```

Output:

```
   index key  value     ratio
0      0   a     10  0.833333
1      1   b     12       NaN
2      2   a     20  1.333333
3      3   b     15       NaN
4      4   a      8  0.888889
5      5   b      9       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `eq`, `cumsum` and `GroupBy.apply` with `shift`.

We use `.eq` to get a boolean where the value is `a` then we use `cumsum` to make an unique identifier for each `a, b` pair.

Then we use `groupby` and `divide` each value by the value one row below with `shift`

```
s = df['key'].eq('a').cumsum()

df['ratio_a_b'] = df.groupby(s)['value'].apply(lambda x: x.div(x.shift(-1)))
```

**Output**

```
  key  value  ratio_a_b
0   a     10   0.833333
1   b     12        NaN
2   a     20   1.333333
3   b     15        NaN
4   a      8   0.888889
5   b      9        NaN
```

---

This is what `s` returns, our unique identifier for each a,b pair:

```
print(s)

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
Name: key, dtype: int32
```

Comment: This would fail if `a` and `b` don't come in pairs as commented by OP.

Comment: Then OP needs to change his question and be more specific, I'm not here to speculate. This is giving the correct results as for now, when OP changes his question, I will edit accordingly. @QuangHoang

Comment: @Erfan
Thank you for taking the time to answer. Sorry if I wasn't clear right from the start. I have edited the question.